# How to convert Keras to Tensorflow Lite and use it from another language?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dart, keras

I've converted keras model (XCeption), but input images still need to be preprocessed (imageNet preprocessing). How to do it in another language (dart in particular)? Is there way to add preprocessing to model?

Comment: [Here is how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65867263/13337635).

Comment: @yudhiesh I need to convert it with preprocess_input function. Probably, I should add it as layer, but still don't know how.

Comment: You are just converting the weights of the model. You would have to do imageNet preprocessing completely separately.